# Image does not overflow container

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

In a vue Project using tailwind for css, i have a flexbox layout with two custom components. The second one is am image that should not shrink or squeeze, but narrow down the viewable area left/right when reducing screen size. Then, the user should be able to scroll the overflow left and right.

The correct approach to my understanding is providing fixed dimensions to the outer div, setting it to block and overflow x scroll. The image has  full height and width. When the container is narrowed, it should overflow.

What happens is that the image just shrinks down as a whole for some reason.

```
  <div class="flex xl:flex-row flex-col">
    <ComponentOne
      class="h-128"
    ></ComponentOne>
    <ComponentTwo class="h-full block max-h-[43rem] max-w-[83rem]  overflow-x-scroll"></ComponentTwo>
  </div>
```

The Component Two looks like this

```
<template>
  <img class="h-full w-full" src="../assets/image.png" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve implies having a wrapper element and a content element. You can't achieve overflow (and scroll) if they're one and the same element.

---

In more detail, if `<ComponentTwo />`'s template two looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <img class="h-full w-full" src="../assets/image.png" />
</template>
```

then

```html
<ComponentTwo class="h-full block max-h-[43rem] max-w-[83rem]  overflow-x-scroll"></ComponentTwo>
```

effectively renders:

```
<img class="h-full block max-h-[43rem] max-w-[83rem] overflow-x-scroll w-full" src="../assets/image.png" />
```

because `<ComponentTwo />`, wherever is used, will get replaced with the exact contents of its template. In other words, `<ComponentTwo />`'s classes will get mapped on its root element, which is the `<img>` element.

You probably want to change its template to:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img class="h-full w-full" src="..." />
  </div>
</template>
```

Or simply wrap `<ComponentTwo />` into a div, bearing the overflow classes you want on it.

---

Additional notes:

- you might want to give the `<img>` classes of `w-auto` and `h-auto`
- you might want to use `.overflow-x-auto` instead of `.overflow-x-scroll`
- always pay close attention to the output (e.g: the resulting DOM elements).

Comment: The actual solution i found based of this one was that for some reason the image tag had an automatically assigned css max width 100%, once i wrapped the component in a div and set the max width of the image to none it worked. But i do wonder why, does img come with included max width?

Comment: @DuBloxx, it might have to do with tailwind's [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#images-are-block-level).